# Помогите решить задачу. Степени

Tags: python, алгоритм, олимпиада, теория-чисел

Пробовал много вариантов, но все они не укладывались в отведённое время. На мой взгляд этот самый близкий к решению. Всё что находил в Google тоже не работало.

> Для того чтобы проверить, как её ученики умеют считать, Мария Ивановна каждый год задаёт им на дом одну и ту же задачу — для заданного натурального A найти минимальное натуральное N такое, что N в степени N (N, умноженное на себя N раз) делится на A. От года к году и от ученика к ученику меняется только число A.
>
> Вы решили помочь будущим поколениям. Для этого вам необходимо написать программу, решающую эту задачу.

## Входные данные:

Во входном файле содержится единственное число A (1≤A≤10⁹ — на всякий случай; вдруг Мария Ивановна задаст большое число, чтобы «завалить» кого-нибудь…).

## Выходные данные:

В выходной файл вывести единственное число `N`.

Примеры

Ввод 8
Вывод 4

Ввод 1
Вывод 1

```
def mn(n):
    lst = []
    i = 2
    while n != 1:
        if n % i == 0:
            n = n // i
            lst.append(i)
            continue
        i += 1
    return lst


x = int(input())
r = mn(x)
y = 2

for i in range(1, len(r)):
    if r[i] != r[i - 1]:
        y = r[i] * y
    i += 1

if x == 1:
    print(1)
else:
    if y >= 29:
        print(y)
    else:
        for k in range(2, 28):
            if x % (y * k) == 0:
                print(k * y)
                break
            k += 1
```

Comment: Что за странные числа 28 и 29?

Comment: Я посчитал, что 29 > 10**9  и нецелесообразно добавлять их в цикл

Comment: Вы посчитали, что 29 больше, чем миллиард???

Comment: 29 в 29 степени

Comment: Так зачем так далеко брать, ведь уже 10¹⁰ больше, чем 10⁹.

Comment: По условию число должно делится на А, после 29 вроде как любое число будет делится на произведение своих простых множителей в степени

Answer (score 1):

Представляю относительно краткое решение:

```
def minimum_number(number_A):
    list_ = []

    for number in range(1, int(number_A ** 0.5) + 1):
        if not (number_A % number):
            list_.append(number)
            list_.append(number_A // number)

    for element in sorted(list_):
        if element ** element >= number_A:
            return element


print(minimum_number(int(input())))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
def Factor(n):
    Ans = []
    d = 2
    while d * d <= n:
        if n % d == 0:
            Ans.append(d)
            n //= d
        else:
            d += 1
    if n > 1:
        Ans.append(n)
    return Ans


lst = Factor(int(input()))
s = set(lst)

num = 1
for i in s:
    a = lst.count(i)
    temp = i
    while temp < a:
        a = a % 2 + a // 2
        temp *= i
    num *= temp
print(num)
```

Comment: Там вообще не вариант в степень пытаться возвести. Оно по времени не подходит

Comment: Где задание можно потестировать?

Comment: https://informatics.msk.ru/mod/statements/view.php?id=19946&chapterid=1009#1

Comment: Вот этот код проходит 14 тестов на сайте)